# How Scala distinguishes between unary operators and characters in variable name

Tags: scala, variables, operators, unary-operator

It seems that in Scala, a variable name can end with specific character, such as -.

How are those trailing characters distinguished from the postfix unary operators during parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters must be joined to the identifier with an underscore.

For example, `a!` parses as `a.!`, whereas `a_!` parses as a single identifier.

Comment: You will see this most notably with the "magic" setter methods (e.g. `bar_=`, which can be called as `foo.bar = 42`) and the unary prefix operators such as the "not" operator (`unary_!` which can be called as `!foo`). Also, some Scala sub-communities prefer Lisp/Ruby-style method naming instead of Java-style for predicate methods (`odd_?` instead of `isOdd`).